# CSV, convert multiple rows in to comma delimited list grouped by another column's value

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have a CSV file with two columns. Column 1 contains a group ID and Column 2 contains an item ID.

Here's some sample data (copied out of excel)

```
- 5 154
- 5 220
- 5 332
- 5 93
- 5 142
- 5 471
- 5 164
- 5 362
- 5 447
- 5 1697
- 5 170
- 6 173
- 6 246
- 6 890
- 6 321
- 6 421
- 6 1106
- 6 5
- 6 253
- 6 230
- 6 551
- 8 2155
- 8 2212
- 8 2205
- 8 2211
- 8 2165
- 8 2202
- 8 1734
- 8 2166
- 8 2129
```

I need to reformat this so that I have just one row for each group ID and Column 2 contains a comma delimited list of item IDs.

So it should look something like this

```
-5   154,220,332,93,142,471,164362,447,1697,170
-6   173,246,890,321,421,1106,5,253,230,551
-8   2155,2212,2205,2211,2165,2202,1734,2166,2129
```

I'm happy to import the CSV in to Excel / Numbers in order to reformat. Or even in to a temp MySQL database if a SELECT query can achieve this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I feel something like this is best solved with *R* and [reshape](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html).
But here you go in Excel:

assuming

- group keys in column A
- item keys in column B
- unique group keys in column D (I guess you can do this manually)

enter into E2:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$50=$D2,ROW($A$2:$A$50),""),COLUMN()-COLUMN($D2)))
```

and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter it as an array formula. Now you can copy cell E2 to F2:P2 and E3:P4.

result:

[image]

Comment: Your solution would make lots more columns for each row. I need the comma delimited list of item IDs to be in column B. So column B's value would be 154,220,332,93,etc,etc.

Comment: That won't be possible with native Excel formulas (you'd need VBA). Workarounds: File->Save As->CSV. Or into E5, enter `=D5&","&E4` and drag that E5 to the right.